# Chodikar watch works only once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm rather new with Node.js.
I would like to "watch" a file containing some parameters to be able to reload it automatically when change are made.

I tried with fs.watch, but it was returning too many event, so I try now with 'chokidar'

```
console.log('Server running');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var watcher = chokidar.watch('test.txt',{ persistent: true });
watcher.on("change", function(path) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toUTCString();
    console.log(n + " : start update");
    console.log(path + " was changed");
});
```

The issue is that it works only once !! When I modify the file 'test.txt', I have the message on the console the first time, but never again after ! 
As if the watcher was removed after the first event ...

The server run under Linux and I installed chokidar today

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the code youve submitted  on linux and it work fine.

I advise you to add the on error event listener as follows:

```
console.log('Server running'); 
var chokidar = require('chokidar'); 
var watcher = chokidar.watch('test.txt',{ persistent: true });     
watcher.on("change", function(path) {
var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toUTCString();
    console.log(n + " : start update");
    console.log(path + " was changed"); }); 
watcher.on('error', error => log(`Watcher error: ${error}`))
```

Pay notice that the not all of the tests are passing for linux and mac os for this module:

[image]

Comment: I rebooted my server and everything is fine now. I know that some part aren't working under Linux, but I really need only to watch one or two files, so it should be ok. Thanks for the 'error' line